Can I use FDR for multiple correction in both stages of a two-stage study using omics data?
Please tell me if I can use FDR for multiple correction in both stages of a two-stage study using omics data. For example, based on RNA-seq data, I would like to identify genes that differ in gene expression between 20 patients and 20 healthy subjects. I am considering a two-stage research design. First, the Student's t-test will be performed on the 10,000 genes as a discovery stage (I know that edgeR or other analysis methods can be used, but since this question is about multiple comparisons, I will use the t-test). The obtained P-values are corrected for false discovery rate (FDR), and q-value < 0.05 is considered significant. As a result, 50 genes showed significant differences. As the next stage, I validate these 50 genes in samples different from those measured by RNA-seq. Another 20 patients and 20 healthy subjects were measured by methods other than RNA-seq and compared again by t-test. Thus, 50 times (50 genes) were tested, so I have to do multiple correction. Can I adapt the FDR again here and assume that q-value < 0.05 is significant? Or should I apply the correction to Bonferro at this stage and set the significance level at P value < 0.05/50 (=0.001)? I would be grateful if you could enlighten me.

The choice is between controlling family-wise error rate (FWER) and false discovery rate (FDR).
Controlling FWER, for example with the Bonferroni method, means trying to ensure that none of your "significant" findings is false. That typically doesn't make sense in a study like yours. If you ever do need to control FWER, the Holm modification provides the same FWER control with more power to identify true positive results.
Wikipedia puts it this way:

For large-scale testing problems where the goal is to provide definitive results, the family-wise error rate remains the most accepted parameter for ascribing significance levels to statistical tests. Alternatively, if a study is viewed as exploratory, or if significant results can be easily re-tested in an independent study, control of the false discovery rate (FDR) is often preferred.

It sounds like your study is of the second type: the first stage is exploratory, and it should be possible to re-test the results of your second stage easily in an independent study. Provided that you clearly state what you have done, there should be no problem with your two-stage approach using FDR control at both stages (although I of course can't rule out potential objections from a reviewer).
